# How to connect two computers using SSH tunneling

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have two linux computers in two different institutes. Computer1 is username1 with host1(internal ip 192.168.1.115) connected to server1(public ip 59.162.19.43). Second Computer2 is username2 with host2(internal ip 192.168.1.120) connected to server2(public ip 158.144.176.220 ). I want to connect to Computer2 from Computer1 using ssh. Please tell me, How can I do?

Thanking you.

Comment: Take a look into this: [http://www.phys.ufl.edu/cms/emu/fast/FAST-DAQ/ssh_between_2.html](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/cms/emu/fast/FAST-DAQ/ssh_between_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make ssh tuneling

for example if you want to connect from Computer1 to Computer2 through Server1 and Server2

on Computer1 run

```
 ssh user@server1_internal_IP -L2002:127.0.0.1:2002
```

on server1 run

```
ssh user@server2_external_IP -L2002:127.0.0.1:2002
```

on server2 run

```
ssh username2@Computer2 -L2002:127.0.0.1:22
```

Then after these operation on Computer1

```
run ssh username2@127.0.0.1 -p 2002
```

Comment: Problem here is I can't run commands on neither server1 nor server2. They are institute's server.

Comment: So, what have you got??

Comment: @esperanto I have got two computers computer1 and computer2 which are connected to server1 and server2 respectively.